Module 'agora_rtc_engine' not found in Xcode run
Xcode run shows the error GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9 Module 'agora_rtc_engine' not found.
I tried flutter clean and pod install. but could'nt work both. Also tried the xcodeproj file to archieve but didnt work all these things for me

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Try below steps

do flutter clean
delete pod folder and pod.lock file from iOS folder
do flutter pub get && cd iOS && pod install --repo-update
check the code again and run it.


Already done all these . But did'nt work. when i run , it shows that 'Parse Issue (Xcode) : Module 'agora_rtc_engine' not found'

Hi @SafeedaKabeer, please try this once https://github.com/AgoraIO-Extensions/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/483
